# Electron/React/Typescript Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in /node_modules/electron

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron

In my Electron app, I have a `App.ts` file that has the following content.

```
import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron';
// rest of the code
```

While I am building an app, this line gives the following error:

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in `/node_modules/electron`

It seems like it is related because this file will be used in the browser.

How can I use `ipcRenderer` in the React part of the application in TypeScript?

Comment: ipcRenderer itself should be the browser portion of electron, and not need to access node's fs module.   fs should be built into node though so maybe it's a typescript thing?  Have you tried adding `@types/node`?   Did you use some template to create the project or are you starting from scratch?

Comment: Yes I have "@types/node": "^16.18.22", installed. I added react later on and works fine unless I try to use `ipcRenderer` on the browser side.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use following:

```
const ipcRenderer = window.require('electron').ipcRenderer;
```